# Как проверить видимость виджета TextView?

Tags: android

У меня одно Активити и на нем 2 заголовка (A и B) сверху.
 Внизу `LinearLayout`, на нем много компонентов... При нажатии на "В" из нижних компонентов только один `TextView` должен скрыться, при нажатии "А", `TextView` обратно должен появиться.
Думал для этого нужно использовать `ViewPager`, но из-за одного Текста писать столько коду думаю неправильно (может, я не прав).

Как реализовать или как проверить скрыт ли `TextView` или нет???

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтобы проверить видимость виджета, следует получить состояние его видимости через метод `getVisibility()` и сравнить с возможными: (`View.VISIBLE`,`View.INVISIBLE`,`View.GONE`):

```
if (textView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    // действия, когда виджет видим
 } else {
    // действия, когда невидим.
 }
```

Для того, чтобы указать видимость для виджета, используется метод `setVisibility()`, имеет три параметра:

`View.VISIBLE` - видим на экране
`View.INVISIBLE` - не видим, но занимает место на разметке
`View.GONE` - невидим и не занимает место на разметке (полностью скрыт)

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось!

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать метод класса View **isShown()**, возвращающий boolean-значение, для получения ответа на вопрос: видимый ли сейчас View-элемент?

Чтобы установить нужную Вам видимость View-элементу, используйте метод **setVisibility(int visibility)**. Советую использовать в качестве аргумента "магические константы": **View.VISIBLE**, **View.INVISIBLE**, **View.GONE**.